# Why DataGrid does not display data from DB

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

I'm having troubles with displaying data from table. The table has one field `PositionName` and build in Entity Framework Code First. For displaying I'm using WPF with MVVM pattern element DataGrid. Code for binding in xaml :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
           x:Name="PositionGrid" Margin="2 2 2 2"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source = PositionCollection}"                  
           SelectedItem="{Binding ThePosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
           SelectionMode="Single" Height="235">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PositionName}"
                             Header="Назва професії"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code behind window

```
public AddPositionView()
{   
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new PositionViewModel();
}
```

Where PositionViewModel is ViewModel and has following code:

```
 public PositionViewModel()
 {
     _db = new SalDBContext();                         
     ThePosition = new Position();
     _poclog = new PositionLogic();    
     PositionCollection = new ObservableCollection<Position>(_poclog.Get());
 }
```

Where `db` is context for working with tables, `ThePosition` – is model class and `_poclog` it's basically class with logic for working with form. Logic class has next implementation for displaying data.

```
 internal IEnumerable<Position> Get()
 {
     return _dbContext.Positions.ToList();
 }
```

Code works without any exceptions and it show form but grid is empty. While debugging `PositionCollection` has all elements from table. When it all goes to code for calling window it shows empty window. After next code it show empty window.

```
 private void PositionShow_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     AddPositionView posview = new AddPositionView();
     posview.Show();
 }
```

According to debugging when I put stop point on `AddPositionView` it goes throw all view model class and `PositionColection` has all elements from db but then it goes back to `AddPositionView` and `posview` become null. Why it happens? And DataGrid display empty table.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PositionCollection` must be a *public property* for you to be able to bind to it:

```
public PositionCollection { get; private set; }
```

You should also set the `Path` of the `Binding` (and not the `Source`) to the name of the property:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PositionCollection}"
```

Comment: Wow thank you problem was with Path) PositionCollection was public with implementation OnPropertyChange) Thank you)